# What's The Difference HTML5 vs Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, animation

I got asked a question that I really didn't know how to answer. "What's the difference between HTML5 and Javascript?" I mean we know HTML is a simple markup language but to get into the things that HTML5 does, such as the `<canvas>` tag for instance; don't you really NEED JavaScript to produce those canvas animations? Would you even be able to make an image slider without any JavaScript assistance? When it comes down to it wouldn't I be able to just use a JavaScript plugin vs HTML5 99% of the time?

Comment: A boat floats on water, ergo boats are water.

Comment: I don't get why people always close thing as "not a real question". This is much closer to the description of "not constructive" than anything... I'm sure this question would spark debates about HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: I think this is a legitimate question.  The fact that HTML5 has been used to refer to a bunch of unrelated developments can be confusing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask, specifically, `there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”`

Comment: The question is "What's the difference between Javascript animations and HTML5 animations" it has nothing to do with opinions i want to know if there are any facts or benefits to using HTML5 versus a javascript plugin that does the something in the end. No where in my original question do I ask for an opinion or anything of the likes.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee You can't do animations in HTML5 without  javascript.

Comment: @Rob that is pretty much the main thing I wanted to know. Thanks Rob...

Comment: @Rob I think hes referring to CSS3 animations, which you can definitely do without javascript. And this question is making me really sad.

Comment: @32bitkid - Apparently not. :)

Comment: Thanks @Rob for actually helping to answer.  Just because there's loads of meganerd know-it-alls on the Stack websites doesn't mean you can't help someone with a basic, legitimate question like Howdy_McGee asked.  Because if he's asking, there's probably thousands of others who have the same question.

Comment: @JaydenLawson This question is NOT legitimate and was closed.

Comment: If I went to a fruit Q&A site and asked 'what is the difference between apples and oranges', I would hope for a technical answer, not a punch in the face @32bitkid and Rob.  It may be obvious to you, but obviously not to people who - errr - have to ask the question.

Comment: I didn't say I *would*, just that I'd *want* to. Richard Feynman was once asked to describe magnetism during an interview, and he becomes visibly flustered. Not because he doesn't know the answer but because any answer that doesn't include at least a superficial understanding of the domain cheats the learner of real knowledge/learning. Given the context of the learner, and the broadness of the question, the best answer I can give is "apples and oranges"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Technically it HTML5 is a standard for the next generation of HTML.  In reality it has become an all encompassing buzzword for javascript and every web technology developed since HTML4.

These are frequently refereed to as HTML5 technologies.

- Javascript
- HTML Canvas
- WebGL
- CSS3
- Other CSS improvements such as flex boxes
- Offline Storage
- Geolocation
- New events such as touch and orientation
- Ajax
- Websockets

Comment: OK, as someone not in the know, I came to this site with exactly this question, and now I am having to look elsewhere.

Answer (score -3):

You cannot create web pages without HTML. Nowadays, javascript is the script of the web and, to do most things dynamically, you need to use it despite the many things CSS3 can even do.

Comment: @RobW - I still don't get it. I said you need HTML. You coded HTML.

Comment: You don't need HTML. XHTML or XML will do.

Comment: @Raynos Note that this is tagged HTML.