# HTML5 vs JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Before anyone loses their mind that I'm "comparing" those two, please hear me out first.

So, I'm quite interested in the new wonderful features that are available recently, with the help of new standards: localstorage, sessionstorage, geolocations, offline web applications, History API etc.
Now, as it can be clearly seen, most of these features are accessed via JavaScript. But when I try to find more about them, it's all related to HTML5.

So, this is why I'm asking, am I not understanding something correctly or are the two terms being widely mixed?

Comment: HTML5 is more of a "zeitgeist" than a single standard.

Comment: You might find your answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650426/whats-the-difference-html5-vs-javascript

Comment: The javascript features you're referring to are part of newer versions of ECMAScript. The fact that most browsers are adopting new versions of ECMAScript at the same time as some of the newer HTML5 features is coincidence. They are not related.

Comment: I don't understand why people are downvoting .... this person clearly has a question here ...

Comment: Nick Karnik thank you for your answer, but I understand the difference between HTML and JavaScript; I just don't understand the latest buzz that seems to be confusing the both terms and was asking to clarify if I'm perhaps wrongly understanding or are , in fact, those two quite misunderstood.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the answer on that thread was useful but it's probably not as useful. HTML5 defines a new standard which browsers implement. Almost all of the features require Javascript unless you're using a simple tag that's part of HTML5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be better to say that they are not competing technologies instead they are both complementary technologies. HTML provides the primary structure (and layout to a degree) of a website wheres JavaScript provides the majority of the interactivity.

No web page can be made without the help of HTML. And Javascript provides the interactivity.

> But when I try to find more about them, it's all related to HTML5.

Yes that is true as mikerobi explained in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650426/whats-the-difference-html5-vs-javascript) that Javascript is referred as HTML5 technology and HTML5 is the next generation of HTML.

The [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) has few points for HTML5 which are good to be listed:

> **Markup**
>
> There is also a renewed emphasis on the importance of DOM scripting
>   (e.g., JavaScript) in Web behavior.
>
> **New APIs**
>
> In addition to specifying markup, HTML5 specifies scripting
>   application programming interfaces (APIs) that can be used with
>   JavaScript.[36]

Also you will find that  Either **JavaScript or CSS3** is necessary for animating HTML elements. Animation is also possible using JavaScript and HTML

Comment: Roughly speaking HTML5 simply provides bundle of API with which javascript can communicate.

Comment: @Givi:- Yes I do understand and accept that!

Answer (score 5):

The "clean" answer, which is now becoming blurred due to the scope creep of the HTML standard, is that HTML is a markup language - which annotates the content of a web page, and javascript is a scripting language which is used to add client-side interactivity to a web page.

The reality is that the HTML5 standard now specifies many related technologies to web pages that previously would have required extra scripting or 3rd party plugins to use on a page. The HTML5 standard attempts to bring all commonly included content types and interactivity into the markup language and the browser so they can be taken for granted by your web page.

This doesn't remove the need for a scripting language such as javascript though. There will always be custom interactivity that developers will need to script into a page, but many common interactions that were coded over and over again are now baked into the HTML5 standard.

Answer (score 4):

You can think of HTML5 not as another iteration of the HTML markup language, but a collection of technologies, of which HTML is part of.  Broadly, I think of HTML5 as "HTML + JavaScript + CSS", though even that doesn't capture the whole picture.

It is unfortunate, in my mind, that HTML5 doesn't refer specifically to HTML.  If I were the W3C, I would have branded the ecosystem of technologies "Web5" or something, which included a new HTML specification.  But I digress.

My favorite introduction to HTML5, Mark Pilgrim's free [Dive into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/), explains it well int the [introduction chapter](http://diveintohtml5.info/introduction.html).

One important thing to realize is that JavaScript is just a programming language.  While it was forged as a browser-based language, it's use as a general-purpose language is taking off, mainly thanks to Node.  So if you look at it in that light, it doesn't make sense to think about local storage, session storage, geolocation, etc., as being features of the language, because these features have little to no meaning outside of the browser.  (One could imagine a situation where a Node server might need geolocation, but it's a stretch....).

Anyway, it's right and proper that the "API cloud" that makes up HTML5 is specific to HTML5, and not part of the JavaScript language.

Comment: Beautifully explained. Simlpy put, we can take html5 as html4 + some fancy new tags + CSS3 + LOTS of browser specific javascript APIs

Comment: If you run for President of W3C (or plan to stage a coup) you have my vote! Web5 is a much better name than HTML5